# Python 3 OOP Redirect method to the attribute's method

Tags: python-3.x, oop, methods

Let suppose I have a class called `A` with an attribute `b` (class or object attribute, it doesn't matter) from a class `B`.

There is a `B` method called `method_B`

If I create an object `a` from class `A`, and I call `a.method_b()` from `a`, I want to be redirected to `a.b.method_b()`

The corresponding code :

```py
class A():

  def __init__(self):
    self.b = B()

class B():

  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 'a string'

  def method_B(self):
    # do something with self.val for example

# MAIN

a = A()

# this:
a.method_B()

# should be the same as:
a.b.method_B()
```

In fact, I want to avoid rewritting the `method_B` in class `A` like this:

```py
class A():

  ...

  def method_B():
    self.b.method_B()
```

I have looked up an use of **property** and with **descriptor** but I don't know how to adapt them (if I can adapt them of course)

*Thank you in advance for your help*

Comment: You are looking for Zope and Acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, when you are trying to get method_B() by creating object of class A, this will cause error since method_B() is not present in the class A.
Your question is that you don't want to rewrite method_B() in class A, so you can use inheritance then you can get the same result from these below mentioned line of code.

this:

`a.method_B()`

will be same as if you will follow below code by using inheritance:

`a.b.method_B()`

```
class B():

  def __init__(self):
    self.val = 'a string'

  def method_B(self):
      print("method B")
   

class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B()
# MAIN

a = A()
b = B()
# this:
a.method_B()

# should be the same as:
a.b.method_B()
```